# verifying integrity of svn backups

Tags: backup, svn

...so I want to back up my Subversion repository and I know how to do that using `svnadmin dump`.

My question is, what is the best way to verify integrity of the dump files?

I figure I'll use them to restore to a mirror server... but then I'm not sure how to compare the original server with the mirror server.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the only more or less reliable way will be restoring it from a backup and running [svnadmin verify](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re41.html) on it. Additionally, you can embed latest revision number to the backup file name (kinda `svn-2009-10-15-r6584.bak`) and then check whether the latest revision in the backed up repo is indeed r6584.

Comment: well, then I guess the question becomes what does svnadmin verify actually do? ("Yup, we verified it. Trust us.")